# Translation errors when I upload CSV file to Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm trying to upload a CSV file into my Rails project, it works, but phone numbers and location coordinates (longitude, latitude) are not being saved properly when I import the CSV file.

**CSV File:**
[image: CSV file snapshot]

**RAILS VIEW:**
[image: Rails view]

**RAKE TASK:**

```
require 'csv'

namespace :csv do

  desc "Import CSV Data for Michelin Star Restaurants"
  task :post => :environment do

    csv_file_path = 'db/data.csv'

    CSV.foreach(csv_file_path, "r:ISO-8859-1" ) do |row|
  Post.create({
                  :name => row[0].to_s.scrub,
                  :address => row[1].to_s.scrub,
                  :city => row[2].to_s.scrub,
                  :michelin_status => row[3],
                  :website => row[4].to_s.scrub,
                  :phone => row[5],
                  :longitude => row[6],
                  :latitude => row[7],
                  :inthenews => row[8],
                  :google_reviews => row[9]
              })
end
    end
  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It probably is related to your database. Show us your table schema so we can see the column types

Comment: and what db are you using?

Comment: Please share the content of `csv` file itself, not how it looked like in Excel/Libre. Looks like an export to CSV casts these fields to integers.

Comment: it seems like phone, longitude, latitude are integers instead of string, decimal, decimal data types

Comment: correct i am saving them all as integers. i'll make the fix you suggest and see if it works

Comment: it worked! thanks patrick!